# Finding Eigen Values from Quantum Phase Estimation - Using qiskit

Tags: programming, qiskit, quantum-phase-estimation, linear-algebra

I am trying to use the quantum phase estimation(EigsQPE) of qiskit to find the eigen values of a matrix.
As I am new to quantum computing so I am confused what to measure in the circuit to derive the eigen values of the input matrix.

I know how to identify phase and derive eigen value using phase derived from the most probable bit string for a single eigen value. But deriving multiple eigen values from QPE circuit is confusing. Any help will be much appreciated.

Code : https://github.com/Anand-GitH/HLL-QauntumComputing/blob/main/Qiskit-QPEStandalone.ipynb

Comment: Hi and welcome to the community! I didn't work with QPE a lot but I am still quite confused about some of the stuff you did on your code: first, you don't use a unitary matrix, I thought the matrix had to be unitary to get the QPE to work, and second you never use the eigenstates on your circuit, but the controlled-evolution are controlled by it, could you elaborate a little bit more on what you did about that?

Comment: Hi Lena, Thank you.  

Its not a unitary matrix I am using a matrix which was mentioned in the qiskit HHL example

https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/hhl_tutorial.html

I have not build any circuit I was just calling QPE of qiskit and I had query on how to measure eigen values from this circuit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things to note:

1. EigsQPE needs the eigenvalues to be scaled onto the range (0,1]. You can use `evo_time` to set the scaling. If you don't pass this value, a scaling value will be set automatically. You can get this value using `eigs.get_scaling()`.
2. If the eigenvalue is $e^{2\pi i\theta}$, then the register contents will be $2^n\theta$

That means if the register contains the value $x$, and `evo_time` equals $s$, then your eigenvalue will be $2\pi x/(2^ns)$

Comment: Hi Egretta,  Thanks a lot with your two points I was able to proceed further. 

https://github.com/Anand-GitH/HLL-QauntumComputing/blob/main/Qiskit-QPEStandalone.ipynb